# PHP fails to post to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a **formText.php** file that contains a form with the following code form code:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="theNames">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="theName" id="theName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="theCitys">City:</label>
        <input type="text" name="theCity" id="theCity">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="theAges">Are you over eighteen?(Y/N)</label>
        <input type="text" name="theAge" id="theAge">
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="theDates">Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="theDate" id="theDate">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then I have an **insert.php** file with the following script:

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root","phpteste");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security (EDITED)
$theName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['theName']);
$theCity = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['theCity']);
$theAge = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['theAge']);
$theDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$_POST['theDate']));


// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabelateste (id, name, city, overeighteen, date) VALUES (NULL, '$theName', '$theCity', '$theAge', '$theDate')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

My database is called phpteste and my table name is tabelateste.
What am I doing wrong here?
Whenever I click Submit nothing comes up and nothing gets added to the database.

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: nop, nothing appears on screen simply.

Comment: You getting incorrect variable name in $_POST

Comment: First verify that the form generated by formText.php is sending the proper data to insert.php by replacing insert.php with a test script that simply dumps/renders the data POSTed. Then verify that insert.php can actually modify the database by hardcoding it to insert a dummy record in your database. Then get them to work together.

Comment: your column name is signup_date but in your insert it is date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post data name fields are wrong. SO you need to change below line:

```
// Escape user inputs for security
$theName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['theName']);
$theCity = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['theCity']);
$theAge = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['theAge']);
$theDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$_POST['theDate']));
```

You need to change `date` to `signup_date` as per your database table structure.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabelateste (name, city, overeighteen, signup_date) VALUES ('$theName', '$theCity', '$theAge', '$theDate')";
```

Comment: Chanage sql to: $sql = "INSERT INTO tabelateste (name, city, overeighteen, date) VALUES ('$theName', '$theCity', '$theAge', '$theDate')";

Comment: Did you get any error while data inserted into database? Or `echo` your query and try to run it directly into database.

Comment: Still did not work. I had the NULL in there because the id was a NULL value. But yet, no luck. Have no idea what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: What is your database structure? Is `id` auto increment and primary key?

Comment: Yes it is. tabelateste (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(20), city VARCHAR (20), overeighteen CHAR(1), signup_date DATE);

Comment: Is it "date" or "signup_date"? because you got  "INSERT INTO tabelateste (id, name, city, overeighteen, date)" and the structure of your table is not marching with the name "date"

Comment: Yeah, major error there but still wasn't it. Ahah, this is messed up.

Comment: Can you please `echo` your query and copy it to your question?

Comment: Re-wrote the whole code differently and it worked with these lines on! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this maybe

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST) ){

$theName = $_POST['theName'];
$theCity  = $_POST['theCity'];
$theAge = $_POST['theAge'];
$theDate = $_POST['theDate'];

            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "root";
            $dbname = "phpteste";

    // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }



        $sql = "INSERT INTO tabelateste (name, city, overeighteen, date)
        VALUES ('$theName ', '$theCity ', '$theAge ', '$theDate ')";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            $last_id = $conn->insert_id;

            } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still returns an empty page. No error but no output nor entry on db.

Comment: Do you have an ID on your DB with auto increment?

Comment: Yes I do, first column.

Comment: I have just taken out id from the sql line. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabelateste (`name`, `city`, `overeighteen`, `date`) VALUES ('$theName', '$theCity', '$theAge', '$theDate')";
```

Use this code

Comment: Tried it and didn't fix it.  Damn it!

Comment: print_r($_POST); use to debug.values are correctly post or not

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code (copied and pasted) and it works perfectly under my server configuration (Windows 10 - PHP 5.6) . My best guess is that you have a typo in either the table name or the MySQL configuration.

If you copied this code from another site. Please check that you created the database and the table , and that the MySQL configuration is correct.

A good to check for this kind of mistakes so is to read the PHP error logs

Comment: I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5.9 and I'm not getting this to work. What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you check the PHP error logs? They tend to be useful